# Retrive data to populate list in single query using MyBatis XML Mapper

Tags: java, sql-server, mybatis

I have three classes:

```
public class Customer{
    public Integer idCustomer;
    public String name;
    public String status;
    public Integer idPlant;
    public List<Worker> workers;
}
public class Worker{
    public Integer idWorker;
    public String name;
    public String lastName;
    public Integer status;
}
public class CustomerWorker{
    public Integer idCustomer;
    public Integer idWorker;
}
```

So I've declared in the XML mapper the resultMap:

```
<resultMap id="CustomerResultMap" type="Customer">
    <result property="idCustomer" column="idCustomer"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <result property="status" column="status"/>
    <result property="idPlant" column="idPlant"/>
    <collection property="workers" resultMap="workerResultMap">
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="WorkerResultMap" type="Worker">
    <result property="idWorker" column="idWorker"/>
    <result property="name" column="name"/>
    <result property="lastName" column="lastName"/>
    <result property="status" column="status"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="CustomerWorkerResultMap" type="CustomerWorker">
    <result property="idCustomer" column="idCustomer"/>
    <result property="idWorker" column="idWorker"/>
</resultMap>
```

I wrote a select statement in order to retrive all the customers, but at this point I'm taking all the customers and then, in a further iteration, I retrive all the worker for each customer.
Of course this solution is not functional, because it forces me to do N+1 iteration (where N is the number of customers in my dataBase).

Is there a way to write a single query in order to populate the worker's list once?
I thought about somenthing like this:

```
 <select id="getCustomers">
  SELECT 
   C.idCustomer,
   C.name,
   C.status,
   C.idPlant,
   (SELECT * 
    FROM Worker W
    INNER JOIN CustomerWorker CW on CW.idWorker = W.idWorker
    WHERE CW.idCustomer = C.idCustomer) as workers
  FROM Customer C 
 </select>
```

but I can't declare a subquery like this in SQL Server.
I'm sure I'm getting something wrong here.

Comment: N+1 problem is mentioned in the [documentation](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html). In the doc, the solution is explained as 'nested results'.

Comment: Can you set fetchingSize parameter in 'select' tag? forexample fetchSize="1000". That shoult resolve your problem.

Comment: You need a single `<resultMap>` with a `<collection>` tag. There's a good example in the docs. This way a single query is run; typically it's blazing fast compared to multiple queries. See the section **Advanced Result Maps** in https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html.